# Silverlight - wrong state after the transition

Tags: silverlight

I am facing the following problem:
I have got custom style button control. It has few states such as:
- Pressed
- MouseOver
- Normal
All of them works properly unless I trigger from this button some other storyboard which transits its. The problem is that when I move mouse over my button (MouseOver state is active), press it (Pressed state is played) and transition begins. During the transition button is moved to different position of the screen but when it finishes despite that mouse is **no longer** on button it is still in state MouseOver. If I move mouse the button changes it state to normal state.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance